# Curvature and plane curves

Tags: curvature

In multi variable calculus I learned the definition of curvature for a plane curve. I used the definition to find a function describing the curvature at various points. What I would like to do is to construct a plane curve given a curvature function. How would I do this?

Thanks,
Bry

Comment: Parametrize your curve by arc-length $s$ and let $\theta(s)$ be the angle between the unit tangent vector and $x$-axis. i.e
$\left(\frac{dx(s)}{ds},\frac{dy(s)}{ds}\right) = ( \cos\theta(s), \sin\theta(s) )$.
Up to a sign, $\frac{d\theta(s)}{ds} =\kappa(s)$ where $\kappa(s)$ is the curvature. Integrate this twice gives you a horrible looking integral:
$$
x(s) + y(s) i = x(0) + y(0)i + e^{i\theta(0)}\int_0^s e^{i\int_0^{s_1} \kappa(s_2) ds_2} ds_1$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of how to proceed

1. Given the curvature function $\kappa\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ define the *angular* function $\theta\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ as
   $$
      \theta(t) = \int_a^t\kappa(u)\,du.
   $$
2. Now define the *tangent* function $T\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ as
   $$
      T(t) = (\cos\theta(t),\sin(\theta(t))
   $$
3. Finally, define the unit-speed curve $\alpha\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ by
   $$
      \alpha(t) = \int_a^tT(u)\,du
   $$
   where the integral denotes the ordered pair of integrals in each of the coordinates of $T$.

---

**Note:** going the other way around, i.e., defining the angular function $\theta$ from the unit speed curve $\alpha$ is a bit trickier, so I will include this here.

1. Start with the tangent vector $T(t)=\alpha'(t)$. Since $\|T(t)\|\equiv1$, for every $t$ we can chose a number $\theta(t)$ such that
   $$
      T(t) = (\cos\theta(t),\sin\theta(t)).
   $$
   Given that this definition says nothing about the continuity or regularity of the map $t\mapsto\theta(t)$, we need to find another way to define a smooth angular function $\theta$.
2. Write $T(t) = (f(t),g(t))$. Then we know that $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions. Pick an angle $\theta_0$ such that
   $$
      T(a)=(\cos\theta_0,\sin\theta_0).
   $$
3. Define the (smooth) function
   $$
      \theta(t) = \theta_0 + \int_a^tfg'-f'g.
   $$
4. To see that $f(t)=\cos\theta(t)$ and $g(t)=\sin\theta(t)$ we need to show that the function
   $$
      \psi = (f-\cos\theta)^2 + (g-\sin\theta)^2
   $$
   is zero everywhere. Since we know that $\psi(a)=0$, it is enough to show that $\psi'\equiv0$.
5. Since $\alpha$ is unit speed, $f^2+g^2\equiv1$ and therefore $ff'+gg'\equiv0$. Compute $\psi'/2$ and using this equation along with $\theta'=fg'-f'g$ conclude that
   $$
      \psi'/2 \equiv0
   $$
   (don't be intimidated by the large expression of the derivative, all terms will cancel.)